# How to make a div responsive which works in old browser too

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Suppose I have images inside a div where I specify div width 100% but images size is not getting responsive.

Here is sample. just see and guide me what kind of CSS I need to add for div as a result whatever is there inside div will be responsive as per screen size.

```
<div class="headerCarouselwrapperOuter" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="headerCarouselwrapper">
            <img src="Images/new-bba-header-image1dyna.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="images/new-bba-header-image2dyna.jpg"  alt="" />
            <img src="images/new-bba-header-image3dyna.jpg"  alt="" />
            <img src="images/new-bba-header-image4dyna.jpg"  alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS too please?

Comment: In what way do you want the images to respond? What does "old browser" mean in this context?

Comment: why people give negative vote for this post ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#headerCarouselwrapperOuter, .headerCarouselwrapper {width:100%;}
.headerCarouselwrapper img {display:block;width:100%;}
```

Add this to your CSS and this should make your images responsive

Answer (score 3):

Default div width in 100%, to make image responsive mention

```
img{
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

in your css.